# Fetch sub query data inside a select statement using case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data in below format

```
   ID  name   order    start Time                       end time
    2   null    1   30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM
    5   null    2   30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
    2   null    4   30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
    5   null    5   30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

First row is the ID and third row is the order

My requirement is when control is at first row then for second column (name) I need to write a separate query where I want to select a record from a table where data is less than end time of first row and it should continue till all rows are completed.

I tried all approaches like writing sub query for second column but every attempt failed.

### Edit

Table 2:

```
Name1   30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM
name2   30-SEP-19 11.16.39.000000000 PM
```

If you see above table I need to query this table with the end time in table1, so final result would be

```
   ID  name   order    start Time                       end time
    2   name1   1   30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM //since name1 record end time is less than record 1 end time
    5   null    2   30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
    2   null    4   30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
    5   null    5   30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Now for second record name filed should be `end time >= record1 endtime and end time < record2 end time`

### Edit

Table2:

```
ID  Name           Start Time                        End Time
2   780     30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM
5   782     30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
2   786     30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
5   788     30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Order of name is not correct, I was able to see correct number of records with wrong order.

`Name column` data in first record of table 2 should be added to first record of table 1 and so on, but this is not in correct order with the solution provided. Also end of both the table2 records can be same as table 1 and less than table 1 but can't be greater than table 1.

### Edit

Table1:

```
   ID  Type Order      start time                          end time
    2   2   1      30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM
    5   2   2      30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
    2   2   4      30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
    5   2   5      30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM  30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Table 2:

```
ID  Name     start time                               end time
2   780  30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM    30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM
5   782  30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM    30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
2   786  30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM    30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
5   788  30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM    30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Now final result would be

```
ID  Type Order    Name          start time                          end time
 2    2    1      780   30-SEP-19 11.13.39.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM
 5    2    2      782   30-SEP-19 11.15.21.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.19.25.000000000 PM
 2    2    4      786   30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
 5    2    5      788   30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Name column value in first row of table2 should be added to table1, till last row. Here end time is the key and I can't use inner join on end time because it can be same for table 1 and table 2 or table 2 end time can be less than table 1 but not greater than.

### Edit

```
ID  Type Order    Name          start time                          end time
 2    2    4      780   30-SEP-19 11.20.08.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.20.59.000000000 PM
 5    2    5      782   30-SEP-19 11.21.00.000000000 PM 30-SEP-19 11.25.02.000000000 PM
```

Comment: What is your expected output form the above data?

Comment: I need to add data into `name` column which I need to search on basis of end time, like `select name from table2 where table2.end_time < end_time` (above query)

Comment: I meant to say, If you got your query, How your final result will look alike.

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.name, T1.order, T1.start_Time, MAX(T1.end_time)
FROM TABLE_1 T1
JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.end_time >= T2.end_time
                AND T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T2.name, T1.order, T1.start_Time
ORDER BY T1.order
```

Alternatively, If you do not have any primary key in your table and is pretty sure that the order would always be deterministic by the end_time in both the table, You can generate a primary key and then join based on that column -

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.name, T1.order, T1.start_Time, MAX(T1.end_time)
FROM (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY end_time) RN
      FROM TABLE_1)  T1
JOIN (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY end_time)
      FROM TABLE_2) T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                       AND T1.RN = T2.RN
GROUP BY T1.ID, T2.name, T1.order, T1.start_Time
ORDER BY T1.order
```

Comment: Bajpal, Thanks for the answer, I was able to achieve 50% of the requirement, Wrong on my part didn't give you the exact set of the data, Edited my question can you please check and help. I was able to get name but order is not correct, Please help

Comment: Its hard for me to determine, What exactly you mean by order. The better option is to edit the question and post the sample data of both your tables and your expected final output.

Comment: Edited question with real time data, can you please help. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @Siva, Can you just let me know what order you are currently getting, which needs to be corrected?

Comment: Please check my edit4, for current query output. thanks

Comment: Now data is duplicating,, I am getting 10 rows where I should have got only 4 rows

Comment: With the most updated query you would get 6 rows instead of 4. The real problem here is absence of Primary keys in both the tables.

Comment: ID will be same, that can be used as primary key,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200501/discussion-between-ankit-bajpai-and-siva).

Comment: I have a thought of using the SP's where iterate for every row and pick the value

Comment: This would be much easier, If end time will always be same as Table 1 end time. But if it can be greater sometimes making it more hard.

Comment: yes actually, but no other way DB is designed in such a way

Comment: Is it possible to have their Start time always same?

Comment: No Even start time will be different, Logic here is these are the dynamic insertion of records and its not in anyone control. Banging my head for few days now.

Comment: Can you please give it a try now. Though it is not the perfect solution, but somehow does the trick for you.

Comment: ok ok , getting your logic, generating a primary key, correct? give me 5 min will update you

Comment: Ok thanks, row number worked, accepting the asnwer.. though I need to check for dependecies but thanks for solution.